# debug assertion fails CScrollView

Tags: c++, mfc

I recently ported an old MFC (multi-threaded) project from VS6 to VS 2015. The project seems to compile but when I launch an action through the GUI I get "Debug Assertion Failed"

> Program: C:\windows\system32\mfc140d.dll File:
>   f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp Line: 962

Then the debug session breaks at following code

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
void CFT100View::AssertValid() const
{
    CScrollView::AssertValid();
}
```

This is my first time working with C++ and MFC. I would greatly appreciate any help to solve this problem.

I followed the call stack. AssertValid eventually goes into wincore.cpp. After loading symbols for wincore.cpp I find this written in the comments just below the assertion failure.

```
    // Note: if either of the above asserts fire and you are
    // writing a multithreaded application, it is likely that
    // you have passed a C++ object from one thread to another
    // and have used that object in a way that was not intended.
    // (only simple inline wrapper functions should be used)
    //
    // In general, CWnd objects should be passed by HWND from
    // one thread to another.  The receiving thread can wrap
    // the HWND with a CWnd object by using CWnd::FromHandle.
    //
    // It is dangerous to pass C++ objects from one thread to
    // another, unless the objects are designed to be used in
    // such a manner.
```

Comment: "*This is my first time working with C++ and MFC*" --  You are making a 6 version jump (maybe more) in compilers, and you didn't expect to get any issues, given you have no experience?

Comment: I did expect some issues. I'm surprised it is compiling without errors. Now I just need to solve this problem.

Comment: Step into ` CScrollView::AssertValid();` this may give more hints.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The callstack should have all the information you need. You are directly or indirectly calling a class member without satisfying its pre-conditions. This usually happens when calling a member too early, or too late in the lifetime of an object, but there could be other reasons as well. Without the code this is just a guessing game, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help @llnsectable! I followed your suggestion and found some interesting commentary in wincore.cpp. see my edit above